# Where is an uninstantiated Integer number going to be located in memory?

Tags: java

I have a question; I don't know if it is dumb or not...but I will ask anyway.
We all know that when we say
`String name = "someName";`
we know that this is a pooled string so it's not going to get on the heap but...

if we say
`Integer integer = new Integer(888);`
we know this is going to get on the heap...
then
`Integer otherInteger = 444;`
where is "otherInteger" going to get? what memory location?
Thanks!

Comment: The compiler will **autobox** the second form. Basically, it becomes [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)). Also, be aware that [`new Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-) is **deprecated** since Java 9.

Comment: `Integer otherInteger = 444;` doesn't mean that it's *uninstantiated*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String name = "someName";   String is *immutable* class and String type is reference or non-primitive type, so name reference point to "someName" object, which is placed in "String-constant- pool", in heap.( no stack).
*Integer is wrapper class( provides the mechanism to convert primitive into object and object into primitive).*
The code Integer otherInteger = 444;  is an example of *auto-boxing* (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) and compiler automatically converts this line to Integer otherInteger = Integer.valueOf(444); . So, Integer otherInteger= Integer.valueOf(444) return Integer object i.e this placed in heap.

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it assisted you.